# Google Sheets / Apps Script: Function to create a new spreadsheet in specific folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to create a new spreadsheet within a specific folder?

I am using the following function to take data from one sheet, validate it and save it in another sheet if it isn't already there.

Additionally I want to create a completely new Spreadsheet in a specific folder, use the data from B8 as its name and fill it with the same data. How do I do that?

```
function validateEntry()
{
  var myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Fahrzeug anlegen");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  shUserForm.getRange("B4").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("B8").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("B11").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("B14").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("B17").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("B20").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("D8").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("D11").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("D14").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("D17").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shUserForm.getRange("D20").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  
  if(shUserForm.getRange("B8").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Fahrzeugnummer eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("B8").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("B8").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("B11").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Fahrgestellnummer eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("B11").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("B11").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("B14").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Marke eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("B14").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("B14").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("B17").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Modell eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("B17").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("B17").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("B20").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Kennzeichen eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("B20").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("B20").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("D8").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("EK-Datum eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("D8").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("D8").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("D11").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("EK-Preis eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("D11").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("D11").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("D14").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Steuer eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("D14").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("D14").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("D17").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Inzahlung eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("D17").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("D17").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  else if(shUserForm.getRange("D20").isBlank() == true)
  {
    ui.alert("Art eingeben!");
    shUserForm.getRange("D20").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("D20").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function submitData() 
{
  var myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Fahrzeug anlegen");
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Masterliste");
  var str = shUserForm.getRange("B8").getValue();
  var values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valuesFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
  {
    var rowValue = values[i];

    if (rowValue[0] == str) 
    {
      shUserForm.getRange("B8").setValue(rowValue[0]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("B11").setValue(rowValue[1]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("B14").setValue(rowValue[2]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("B17").setValue(rowValue[3]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("B20").setValue(rowValue[4]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("D8").setValue(rowValue[5]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("D11").setValue(rowValue[7]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("D14").setValue(rowValue[8]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("D17").setValue(rowValue[9]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      shUserForm.getRange("D20").setValue(rowValue[10]).setFontFamily("Courier New").setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert("Eintrag schon vorhanden!");
      return;
    }
  }

  if(valuesFound == false)
  { 
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert("Speichern", 'Daten speichern?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
    if (response == ui.Button.NO) 
    {
      return;
    } 

    if (validateEntry() == true) 
    {
      var blankRow = datasheet.getLastRow()+1; // nächste leere Zeile finden
  
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B8").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B11").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B14").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B17").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B20").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D8").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D11").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D14").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D17").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D20").getValue());

      ui.alert(' "Neues Fahrzeug gespeichert: #'+ shUserForm.getRange("B8").getValue() +'" ');
    
      shUserForm.getRange("B4").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("B8").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("B11").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("B14").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("B17").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("B20").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("D8").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("D11").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("D14").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("D17").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      shUserForm.getRange("D20").clear().setBackground('#FFFFFF').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, '#d9d9d9', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ui.alert("Eintrag schon vorhanden!");
    ui.alert("Kein Eintrag gefunden!");
  }
}
```

Comment: One of the problems I came to realize is that with each new container comes a new project and as the list of projects abound the complexity for managing them abounds equally.   And so for example I no longer backup my code by saving backups of the containers.

Comment: Instead I store the code and sheet backups as ascii/json file backups which are simple ascii files that are easily read by both  human and machine and do not require google to create any additional projects.  At some point in the future if I wish I can recreate the projects with app script api but most of the time they will be deleted after the project has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: You asked about creating a new spreadsheet in a specific folder, named with data from specific cell.

This function does that. It takes the desired filename as an input, so you can just call it from within one of your other functions and pass the value of cell B8 as the desired `name`.

```
function newSpreadsheet(name){
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('[FOLDER ID]')
  var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create(name).getId()
  destination.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(newFile))
}
```

**Breakdown**

`var destination` sets the target folder for the new file. You will need to put the desired folder location into the script, which you can get from the URL of the folder.

`var newFile` creates a new Google Sheet, naming it with the `name` you pass to this function. It returns the ID of the new file.

`destination.addFile` moves the new file into the destination folder.

Comment: Actually I would like to create a new, empty Spreadsheet, how would I do that?